# Plotting the electric field and potential of a dipole

Tags: plotting, physics

This is a function that takes a function, turn it into a vector, then plots the vector and its contour.

```
plot[ϕ_] := 
     Module[{Efield = -{D[ϕ, x], D[ϕ, y]}, plot1, plot2}, 
      plot1 = ContourPlot[ϕ, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
        ContourShading -> False, DisplayFunction -> Identity]; 
      plot2 = VectorPlot[Efield, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
        VectorScale -> Small, DisplayFunction -> Identity]; 
      Show[plot1, plot2, DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction]]

ϕ = 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 0.5)^2] - 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y + 0.5)^2];
plot[ϕ]
```

This is my output:

[image: Output]

However the plot supposed to look like this:

[image]

Why is my output so different and how can I fix it?

I have been studying notes from an undergrad course that used Mathematica 5, so my knowledge of it is rather outdated.

Comment: try `StreamPlot` instead of `VectorPlot` However, it seems unlikely that you get the desired plot since you have maxima in the places that vectorplot correctly shows but your "supposed" plot omits.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa Then what might be wrong with `VectorPlot` for this problem?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for tsuresuregusa's advice, I changed VectorPlot to StreamPlot. It produced the correct output (which is the electric field of a dipole).

```
plot[ϕ_] := 
 Module[{Efield = -{D[ϕ, x], D[ϕ, y]}, plot1, plot2}, 
  plot1 = ContourPlot[ϕ, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    ContourShading -> False, DisplayFunction -> Identity]; 
  plot2 = StreamPlot[Efield, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    VectorScale -> Small, DisplayFunction -> Identity]; 
      Show[plot1, plot2, DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction]]
ϕ = 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 0.5)^2] - 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y + 0.5)^2];
plot[ϕ]
```

[image]

Comment: Since you mentioned that you were adapting version 5 code, here's a modern version of your code: `plot[ϕ_] := Show[ContourPlot[ϕ, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourShading -> False], StreamPlot[-D[ϕ, {{x, y}}] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, VectorScale -> Small]]`

Comment: Thank you J.M. The piece of code I used were for demonstrating modular programming, I guess it was actually unnecessary in this case.